# java oop array list from one form to another

Tags: java, arrays, oop, jcombobox

I created an array list that will take the ID of the consultant and save it in this array when pressing the save button:

```
Person cons_save = new Person();
    cons_save.setPersonfirstname(this.jTextField1.getText());
    cons_save.setPersonlastname(this.jTextField2.getText());
    cons_save.setPersonID(this.jTextField3.getText());
    this.jTextField1.setText("");
    this.jTextField2.setText("");
    this.jTextField3.setText("");

    cons_save.savecons();

   ArrayList<String> idList = new ArrayList<String>();

   idList.add(cons_save.PersonID);
```

Now I would like to get this array list and display it in a drop down list on another form.

```
   private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    // TODO add your handling code here:
     String[] array = idList.toArray();
     JComboBox jcombobox1 = new JComboBox(array);
}
```

I am keeping receiving error that the jcombobox and the idlist symbol cant be found so the drop down list is staying empty.

Answer (score 1):

Your idList isn't listed in your function. what I suggest you to do is to declare it as a global variable so that it could be accessed by the function.

```
static void main(String ar[])
{
int x;
func();
}
void func()
{
System.out.println(x); //here x is not defined.
}
```

**declaring it global**

```
int x; 
static void main(String ar[])
    {
    x = 10;
    func();
    }
    void func()
    {
    System.out.println(x); //here x is defined.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your idList is a local variable which you try to access from a different method (not the one you declared variable in). You probably should make idList an instance property.

Comment: so I should create the array in the person class?

Comment: @RyanTheuma I don't think you should create it in Person class. As far as I understand your forms interact somehow (e.g. the first one creates the second one after button click or whatever). So you can keep your array list as the instance property of the first form (the one that creates this Person) and then pass it as argument constructor for example to the second form when you instantiate it.

Comment: there are 3 forms mainmenu, customer and consultant, you need to go back to main menu to access the customer when creating the consultant